# c char array copy and concat with formatting leaves off \n and replaces with ÿ

Tags: c, char, uart, c-strings, blackfin

I have a small c program to copy input from an algorithm into a final char array that is then sent over serial (UART) to a raspberry pi.  The problem is the last character in the char array is always a latin-1 character of the ÿ (\xff).

The sprintf formatting works great but when i create a new char buffer to limit the size of the array and only copy the contents it seems to strip off the \n and append the \xff or ÿ depending upon what encoding you are using in the pi for the serial reader.

```
char accel_string[50] = "";
sprintf(accel_string, "B:%d|A:%d\n", dataB, dataA)
// I can see "B:123|A:123\n\0" in the char array now

int str_length = strlen(accel_string);
char trunc_str[str_length];

strncpy(trunc_str, accel_string, str_length);
// Now it sets trunc_str to "B:123|A:123\xff

// Blocking TX right now - write over serial
eResult = adi_uart_Write(ghUART, trunc_str, sizeof(trunc_str));
```

trunc_str keeps ending with the ÿ when I would expect it to end in the "\n"

Help me where I went wrong.

***Update*** based on comments with putty results
[image]

***Update #2***
I have verified that a '\n' anywhere in the char array gets removed and replace with the ÿ.  I looked at the watch variable on the char array and when its sent to the uart_write the \n exists.  After the buffer is coverted to a unit8_t in the uart code it seems to strip off the \n.  I have even tried a unit8_t with a '\n' and it strips out after calling the uart_write code.  I have reached out to analog.com and will update this post once there is a resolution.

Comment: `char trunc_str[str_length];` --> `char trunc_str[str_length + 1];` followed by `strcpy`. Also note that the return value from `sprintf` saves you wasting resources calling `strlen`.

Comment: There's no reason for `trunc_str`. Just `adi_uart_Write(ghUART, accel_string, str_length);` And as already mentioned, the return value from `sprintf` *is* the correct value for `str_length`.

Comment: Still getting the odd character after trying both suggestions.  I wonder if it is a specific issue with the Analog DSP board i am using.
B:779|A:15065ÿ

Comment: Hmm, what happens if you change the format string in the `sprintf` to `"B:%d|A:%d|hello\n"`

Comment: Updated post with screenshot of putty results, same deal.

Comment: How do you "see" what is in the char array?

Comment: anyway, add extra debugging or whatever to confirm the contents of the array immediately before the call to `adi_uart_Write`. If it is correct at that point then you can blame the serial comms (could be either end).

Comment: I think it is the serial com library I am using.  I will update once I hear back from the dsp company and can mark this complete if so.